# Static files are not found django 1.9

Tags: django

I am trying to deploy my website on https://www.pythonanywhere.com/. My website was doing fine on the localhost with following settings:

```
"""
Django settings for islamic project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '1(v#inp4vbreuw63xa*p&7$(_4+csha0e==86%m8v!ur-(bm5+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'whoismuhammad'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'islamic.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            TEMPLATE_PATH
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'islamic.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

When I uploaded my files to server, the static files are not found. Even the django admin panel is not loading css and js files.

Edit:

So, as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/, I changed the settings.py as follows:
added

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/quoteofmuslims/islamic/static/"
```

and run:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

This gave me an error:

> STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting

To overcome this I made another folder in my project called `mystatic` and set this path to root project:

```
   STATIC_ROOT = "/home/quoteofmuslims/islamic/mystatic/"
```

After it, I again ran:

```
 $ python manage.py collectstatic
```

It worked well, copied some files. But,still It is unable to find files.

Edit 2 :

I ran following command:

```
python manage.py findstatic css/bootstrap.css
```

It gives me :

```
Found 'css/bootstrap.css' here:                                                                               
/home/quoteofmuslims/islamic/static/css/bootstrap.css
```

Edit 3:

My current settings.py is:

```
"""
Django settings for islamic project.
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.4.
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '1(v#inp4vbreuw63xa*p&7$(_4+csha0e==86%m8v!ur-(bm5+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'whoismuhammad'
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'islamic.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            TEMPLATE_PATH
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'islamic.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/quoteofmuslims/islamic/mystatic/"
STATIC_URL = '/mystatic/'
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: have a look on my edits.

Comment: Does the server know where to pick up the static files?

Comment: @Evert how should I check that?

Comment: My live website is: http://quoteofmuslims.pythonanywhere.com/.

Comment: Did you read through https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles ? The `STATIC_ROOT` suggestion there doesn't resemble your `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: It tells to use: "/home/myusername/myproject/static". I have done the same. STATIC_ROOT = "/home/quoteofmuslims/islamic/mystatic/" to be precise.

Comment: Your question says `STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/mystatic/"` though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108799/discussion-between-learner-and-evert).

Comment: What is your `STATIC_URL`. And did you check online whether you can access any of your static files directly, like suggested in that help of PythonAnywhere?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. I am unable to access any of my static files. The error is: The current URL, static/css/bootstrap.min.css, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Change your `STATIC_URL` to `mystatic`, obviously. It should match (the last part of) your `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: Can you update your question with your current settings? Including the new STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: Also, you may want to change your secret_key, since your current one is exposed here.

Comment: Did you perform the other steps given in the help? Like setting up the static file mapping on the server?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. But, still I am stuck at this point.

Comment: While I am trying to access these files in my browser: http://quoteofmuslims.pythonanywhere.com/mystatic/css/bootstrap.min.css, I am getting error like:Using the URLconf defined in islamic.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$
The current URL, mystatic/css/bootstrap.min.css, didn't match any of these.